# Use arbitrary number of arguments in class generics - Java

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if it would be possible to use an arbitrary number of arguments in class generics? In methods, it is possible using '...' which is why I'm wondering if there is a similar way for this to be done in class generics

```
Class<T ...>
```

Something like the one above.

Comment: For what would that be useful?

Comment: I was thinking of making a Map that accepted multiple values so I wanted to try the above method so that a user could put as many generic types as necessary.

Comment: Still don't see the use case. What method in such a class could benefit from it?

Comment: Not so much a method in a class but more of for a user. For example, a user wants to store in a map a person's name, age, and id. Instead of creating a wrapper class or creating a list, it would be possible to simply store the additional values and call them as necessary via indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Each type-parameter must be separately specified and they have to be unique in terms of naming.

For example:

```
public class SomeClass<A, B, C, D> { .... } //valid

public class SomeClass<A, A, B, B> { .... } //wrong, because the names are not unique
```

Comment: Would it be possible for a constructor to add type-parameters?

Comment: Yes. Just like it's possible for methods.

Comment: Sorry, I mean would it be possible for a constructor to add type-parameters for the class generics? For example, the class only possesses <A, B> as its type parameters, would it be possible for a constructor to add type-parameters to the class itself at run-time? This way, instead of just <A, B> for the class, the constructor can add more parameters so the class would become <A, B, C> and so on.

Comment: No. When introducing a type-parameter for a method (or a constructor), the type-parameter is valid only for the scope of the method (or the constructor). If you want the type-parameter to have wider scope, it has to be defined on class level.